# How to bring sum of previous column in to next column automatically, in Excel or Google Sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, iwork-numbers

I'm new to this. I'm trying to make a personal budget sheet, where I can bring the previous months' sum into the next month's column as "savings from last month". Basically I want to show the summation of previous column into a cell of next column. This will continue until infinite columns. So is there any way to automate this instead of doing `=SUM(A1:A3)`, `=SUM(B1:B3)` and so on for each column?

Here is a reference image of what I want to achieve. Please remember, I have no prior experience in this and I just want to create a simple budget/savings tracker for myself. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Well you set the formula `=SUM(A1:A3)` for the first cell and then you can drag right to fill the entire row (if you select that cell it will have a square in bottom right corner, click it and drag it to the right to fill with the formula). It will automatically change from A1:A3 to B1:B3 and so on. And for the B1 cell you just type `=A4` (aka sum cell) and drag it right as well.

Comment: Excel is made for this kind of thing. Have a search on youtube for an intro to relative and absolute references e.g. like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSNuRasYl60

Comment: Thank you. The `=A4` worked.